# Moving pointer in StreamReader

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a file containing blocks (header and body). I need to seperate out the blocks. Header is 'he=' and body can be anything e.g. 'boulder is heavy'. So a typical file could look like

he=sunny dayhe=boulder is heavyhe=hello everyone

I am using StreamReader's Read method to read character by character.

In the program, using if statement I check for h e and = to determine if its header. But consider the word heavy. I would need a way to move the file pointer back to h since its not a header.

Is there a way we can move file pointer in StreamReader? The above header body example is just a toy example for explanation.

Comment: no you cannot. The StreamReader is a forward only reader and you can peek without consuming the next character.

you maybe best looking at the FileStream instead. It does have a Seek method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is it a big file? It would be more efficient to load large amounts of data and "parse" the file in memory.

Comment: @Stefan It is a big file 400 MB. I wouldn't like to bring it to memory.

Comment: Then try to use chucks if possible. Reading a file -per byte- is really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Since the StreamReader is forward only, there's no way that you can go backwards. However all is not lost. A common tactic is to use a *buffer* variable and check that. Here's some rough code:

```
var buffer = new StringBuilder();

while(streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
{
    //Add latest character to buffer
    buffer.append(streamReader.Read());

    //Check the three rightmost characters in the buffer for the occurance of he=
    if(buffer.Length >= 3 && buffer.ToString().Substr(buffer.Length-3, 3) == "he=")
    {
        //We have found new header. Now we trim the header from the rest of the buffer to get the body
        var newBody = buffer.ToString().Substr(0,buffer.Length-3);
        //I'm assuming you'll be adding the body somewhere
        bodies.Add(newBody);
        //Now we clear the buffer
        buffer.Clear();
    }
}
//What's left in the buffer is also a body
bodies.Add(buffer.ToString());
```